# How does AWS know where my imports are?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda and pretty new to Python.

I wanted to write a python lambda that uses the AWS API.

boto is the most popular python module to do this so I wanted to include it.

Looking at examples online I put `import boto3` at the top of my Lambda and it just worked- I was able to use boto in my Lambda.

How does AWS know about boto? It's a community module. Are there a list of supported modules for Lambdas? Does AWS cache its own copy of community modules?

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) seems to suggest `boto3` is provided by default on AWS Lambda:

> AWS Lambda includes the AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3), so you don't need to include it in your deployment package. However, if you want to use a version of Boto3 other than the one included by default, you can include it in your deployment package.

As far as I know, you will need to manually install any other dependencies in your deployment package, as shown in the linked documentation, using:

```
pip install foobar -t <project path>
```

Comment: Ah I missed that, well thats a relief I was super confused!

Answer (score 3):

AWS Lambda's Python environment comes pre-installed with `boto3`. Any other libraries you want need to be part of the zip you upload. You can install them locally with `pip install whatever -t mysrcfolder`.

Comment: will -t put them in my current directory?

Comment: If you use `-t .` it will. You need to pass an extra argument with the target folder. I recommend creating a simple build script that creates a temporary folder, copies all the source code there, calls `pip install -r /tmp/xxx/requirements.txt -t /tmp/xxx` and then zips up the entire folder.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda includes the AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3), so you don't need to include it in your deployment package.

This link will give you a little more in-depth info on Lambda environment
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

And this too
https://alestic.com/2014/12/aws-lambda-persistence/